# Android Room SQL Query - How can I run a query with a conditional WHERE clause

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

So I would like to run an SQL query which obtains values from multiple tables.
I wish to get the:

- exerciseName and exerciseID from the exercises_table
- junctionID from the exercise_junction_table
- setNumber, minReps, maxReps from the exercise_workout_goals table

I then also have a log_entries_table.

This table stores information about an exercise which the user has logged.
From this table I wish to get the COUNT of all logs for a specific date if any are present.

If no logs are present on the date, I would like the return value to be 0.

[ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIfS5.png)

From my research it seems as though I would need some sort of conditional WHERE clause, but only if a log_entry exists on the date which is passed to it.

If there is no log present, I would simply like the `WHERE date = :date` section to be ignored.

At the moment, my query is only returning results in which a logEntry is present because of my `WHERE date = :date` 
(the date is obtained from the log_Entries table, therefore if a log is not present, there will not be any date at all).

I cannot workout how to make the `WHERE date = :date` conditional and only run it on the exercises in which at least one logEntry is present.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**My current query** (This only returns values in which a logEntry on the date it is passed is present.)

```
 @Query("SELECT exercises_table.exercise_Name, exercises_table.exercises_id, 

exercise_workout_goals_table.set_number, 

exercise_workout_goals_table.junction_id, exercise_workout_goals_table.min_reps,  

exercise_workout_goals_table.max_reps, log_id, COUNT(log_id) AS logs_today  FROM 

exercises_table LEFT JOIN exercise_workout_junction_table ON 

exercises_table.exercises_id = exercise_workout_junction_table.exercise_id LEFT 

JOIN exercise_workout_goals_table ON 

exercise_workout_junction_table.exercise_workout_id = 

exercise_workout_goals_table.junction_id JOIN log_entries_table ON 

exercise_workout_junction_table.exercise_workout_id = 

log_entries_table.junction_id WHERE exercise_workout_junction_table.workout_id = 

:button_id AND log_entries_table.date = :date  ORDER BY 

exercise_workout_goals_table.junction_id; ")

  LiveData<List<ExerciseAndGoal>> getAllWorkoutExercises(int button_id, String date);
```

**Exercise and Goal Entity**

(This contains all of the fields in which I would like to obtain)

```
public class ExerciseAndGoal {

    private String exercise_name;
    private int set_number;
    private int min_reps;
    private int max_reps;
    private int exercises_id;
    private int junction_id;

    private int log_id;

    private int logs_today;


    public String getExercise_name() {
        return exercise_name;
    }

    public void setExercise_name(String exercise_name) {
        this.exercise_name = exercise_name;
    }

    public int getSet_number() {
        return set_number;
    }

    public void setSet_number(int set_number) {
        this.set_number = set_number;
    }

    public int getMin_reps() {
        return min_reps;
    }

    public void setMin_reps(int min_reps) {
        this.min_reps = min_reps;
    }

    public int getMax_reps() {
        return max_reps;
    }

    public void setMax_reps(int max_reps) {
        this.max_reps = max_reps;
    }

    public int getExercises_id() {
        return exercises_id;
    }

    public void setExercises_id(int exercises_id) {
        this.exercises_id = exercises_id;
    }

    public int getJunction_id() {
        return junction_id;
    }

    public void setJunction_id(int junction_id) {
        this.junction_id = junction_id;
    }



    public int getLog_id() {
        return log_id;
    }

    public void setLog_id(int log_id) {
        this.log_id = log_id;
    }

    public int getLogs_today() {
        return logs_today;
    }

    public void setLogs_today(int logs_today) {
        this.logs_today = logs_today;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe "AND (log_entries_table.date = :date OR log_entries_table.date is NULL)"?

Comment: I have just tried that, the query is still only returning values which have a log_entry present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use just "JOIN" in last clause, it's equal to "INNER JOIN".

This "INNER JOIN" throw out your rows from result where that condition is false:

```
exercise_workout_junction_table.exercise_workout_id = log_entries_table.junction_id
```

Replace your last "JOIN" with "LEFT JOIN" and with modification I've written in comment:

```
AND (log_entries_table.date = :date OR log_entries_table.date is NULL)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, this is almost working. It only seems to be returning 1 result however. Is there anything in the query which could be causing this?

Comment: No, I can't see any visible problem. Try to analyse query result in some db browser for sqlite [DB Browser] (https://medium.com/@mattyskala/browse-sqlite-database-in-android-studio-4fbba6cca105) for example. Common way - get away one by one WHERE-conditions (you don't have a lot of them) and thus detect which condition causes the problem